# my javascript code not stoping

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code and this is my first code. When i press number it shows you have been passed. after this when i press enter again it shows you have been failed. Why my code showing two results?

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var number=prompt("please enter your number")

if ( number >= 33) {
    alert("you got passed");
} 
if ( number <= 32) 
{
    alert("You have been failed");
} 
else {
    alert("Please enter a valid number")


}
```

Comment: You forgot the first `else` between the two first `if` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you are getting two alerts is the fact you missed an else on the second if.

You should also not that prompt returns a string, not a number. So your comparison is not doing what you think it is doing.

If you want ints only

```
var number = prompt("please enter your number");
number = parseInt(number,10);
```

If you want floats

```
var number = prompt("please enter your number");
number = parseFloat(number);
```

And you should use an else if and check for not a number to start.

```
if (isNaN(number)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid number");
} else if ( number >= 33) {
    alert("you got passed");
} else {
    alert("You have been failed");
}
```

Comment: Yep, I was just gonna say ...

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your prompt:

```
var number=parseInt(prompt("please enter your number"),10);
```